# 2x2 GridLayout with squares

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want a 2x2 grid layout, that fills the whole width of the screen with CardViews that are squares.

Currently, I have this

[image]

The CardViews are being stretched to the height of the GridLayout. How can I make it so that the CardView heights are matching its widths so I have squares?

My current XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jonas.trainingslog1.Activity_Settings"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>


</GridLayout>
```

I have searched a lot but nothing really helped yet, any advice is welcomed!

Comment: Right now your grid has match_parent width and 600dp height and items inside are sharing this area equally. So, if you want them to be square you need a square grid. 
Simply, you can set width and height of your grid something like 600dp. But of course, this wont fit screen in each phone. You need to calculate this size dynamicly.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that I could set the width and height to a constant value but as you said it would´t fit the screen. The answer by Vishva Dave solved this inside xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try :**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>


    </GridLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks that works, I don´t understand why but the View item under the GridLayout makes it work.

Comment: One more thing, I noticed it doesn´t work anymore when you put the Linear Layout into a ScrollView. Do you know a way to fix this?

Comment: Make it nested scrollview instead scrollview

Comment: _I don´t understand why but the View item under the GridLayout makes it work_ because it just creates a dummy space. and it is given some weight so in all screens it will be of same height. weights are used for alternative of fix height

Answer (score 1):

Try setting CardView width and height to some expected equal values eg 200dp:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    (...)
```

EDIT:

Or try setting:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```